# Passing a custom object to BroadcastReceiver results via intent returns null

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to pass a custom data class object from a foreground service to a BroadcastReceiver. I have tried using Parcelable, Parcelize and Serializable, but the BroadcastReceiver intent always reports it as null.

I have wasted a couple of days searching for an answer and have looked at some of the threads here and elsewhere. The accepted answers that work for others are not working for me.

Here's the service:

```
class MyService : Service(){

............
<Some code that initialises alarmTimeInMillis>
............

    private fun sendDataToReceiver(){
       val intentMyRcvr : Intent = Intent("Data", null, this, MyReceiver::class.java)
       intentMyRcvr.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND)
       val bundle = Bundle()
       val myParcel = MyParcel(dataP.Id, dataP.Location, dataP.Title, dataP.Description, dataP.Type)
       bundle.putParcelable("MyParcel", MyParcel)
       intentMyRcvr.putExtras(bundle)
       val pendingIntentMyRcvr= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, dataP.Id, intentMyRcvr, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
       val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
       alarmManager.setWindow(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimeInMillis, 5 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntentMyRcvr)
    }
}
```

Here's the BroadcastReceiver:

```
class MyRcvr : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == "Data") {
            val bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("MyParcel")
            val myParcel = bundle.getParcelable<MyParcel>("MyParcel")

            val intentToService = Intent("Data", null, context, MyService::class.java)
            if (myParcel != null) {
                intentToService.putExtra("MyParcel", MyParcel)
                context.startService(intentToService)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Parcelize data class:

```
@Parcelize
data class MyParcel(
    var Id: Int = 0,
    var Location: String,
    var Title: String,
    var Description: String,
    var Type: String,
) : Parcelable
```

I've also tried without using Bundle i.e. directly passing the parcelable object. Neither produces any error in the service but, the the rceiver always reports it as null. I have included the stack trace  from logcat:

> 4081-4081/a.b.c E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: a.b.c, PID: 4081
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver a.b.c.AlarmsRcvr: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable
>   android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3389)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:200)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1662)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable
>   android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference
>           at a.b.c.MyRcvr.onReceive(MyRcvr.kt:21)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3380)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:200) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1662) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

I am beginning to wonder if it is a bug in the latest SDK or Kotlin Plugin. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Android Studio version - 3.5.0

Comment: Gradle version - 5.4.1, API 28, Kotlin - 1.3.50

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
   bundle.putParcelable("MyParcel", MyParcel)
```

to

```
   bundle.putParcelable("MyParcel", myParcel)
```

Please note the lowercase 'm' in the second line.

Comment: That's the way I have it in my project. I made a mistake here while pasting some and typing in yet some! My apologies.

Comment: As I mentioned in OP, sending the parcel works, but the receiver doesn't receive it.

Comment: I do not see the option to edit OP, I wonder if someone else can do it for me and correct the mistake!

Comment: Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I'd say leave it, as someone else might point out the same error. Thanks